# Inserting Data in to the MySQL Database by clicking submit button in JSP

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

Following code is to get data from the database, update and set data to the database by JSP by clicking on a submit button in HTML.

```
 <%
    String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pmsdb";
    String USERNAME = "dbuser";
    String PASSWORD = "dbpassword";

    Connection conn=null;
    ResultSet rs =null;
    ResultSet rs2 =null;

    Statement stmt=null;
    Statement stmt2=null;

    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    PreparedStatement pst2=null;
    PreparedStatement pst3=null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    String pno = request.getParameter("PONo");


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM purchaseorderinfo WHERE PONo='"+pno+"'";
    String sql2 ="SELECT * FROM itemspoinfo WHERE PONo='"+pno+"'";

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    stmt2=conn.createStatement();
    rs2=stmt2.executeQuery(sql2);
    %>  

    <%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);


    if(request.getParameter("btnacc")!=null){

        //getting todaydate
        Date date = new Date();
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());  

        String sql3="UPDATE itemspoinfo SET AorD=1 WHERE PONo='"+pno+"'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
        pst.execute();

        String sql4="INSERT INTO pointoinvoce (InvoiceDate, Company, ItemName, Qty, Price, PONo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql4);

        int noofdrugs=0;

        while(rs2.next() && rs.next()){
           String name =rs2.getString("ItemName");
           String qty = rs2.getString("Qty");

           pst2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
           pst2.setString(2, rs.getString("Supplier"));
           pst2.setString(3, name);
           pst2.setString(4, qty);
           pst2.setString(5, rs2.getString("Price"));
           pst2.setString(6, pno);
           pst2.addBatch();
           noofdrugs++;

        }
        pst2.executeBatch();

    }

    if(request.getParameter("btnde")!=null){

        String sql5="UPDATE itemspoinfo SET AorD=1 WHERE PONo='"+pno+"'";
        pst3= conn.prepareStatement(sql5);
        pst3.execute();
    }
    %>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="citydetails">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Purchase Order Details</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table">
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Purchase Order <%=request.getParameter("PONo") %></th>
                    </tr>   
              </thead>
            <tbody>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <% if(rs.next()){ %>
                            Purchase Order Date : <%= rs.getString("PODate") %><br>
                            Expected Date : <%=rs.getString("ExpectedDate") %> <br>
                            <% } %> 

                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Items</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                    </tr>
                                     <% while (rs2.next()){ %>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td><%=rs2.getString("ItemName")%></td>
                                        <td><%=rs2.getString("Qty")%></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <% } %>


                                </tbody>

                            </table>



                        </td>

                    </tr>

            </tbody>

            </table>
                <button type="submit" name="btnacc" class="btn btn-primary accept" id="btnacc" onclick="clickabtn()">Accept</button>   
                <button type="submit" name="btnde" class="btn btn-primary accept" id="btnde" onclick="clickdbtn()">Decline</button>



      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

but when **btnacc** button is clicked nothing happens in the database table.

And when **btnde** button is clicked nothing happens in the database table.

What is the error here and please  help me to fix this?

Comment: missing port number in the `jdbc` url? jdbc:mysql://localhost`:3306`/pmsdb . Make sure the database connection is established, do a `null` check on `conn` object, so that you know db is connected or not and where the flow is going to.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML must be enclosed by a `<form> ... </form>`, he is the responsible for gathering the information and sending server side. If you dont specify the destination address for the submission it will assume it's the current page (which will work just fine for a servlet), and if you dont specify the method it will send it by GET method by default.

Check about the servlet lifecycle, your code is in fact JSP. In the back end it will generate a servet that is not concurrency compliant. Meaning that you have to threat this kind of issue by yourself. Example: two client requests done at the same time may result in colision and interference with each other submission, probably producing ConcurrentModicationException on the server side.